# Left aligning equations without align character

Tags: amsmath, align

I realise that this has been asked many times before, but no answers I've found seem to provide a solution to my question.

I'd like to left align all text in an `align` block, in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
b := (a \oplus s_1) \oplus s_2 \\
e := 0 \\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This presents me with:

[image]

If I change the first line to `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}` , then instead I get:

[image]

What I'm really looking for is the ability to align the first character on every line in the `align` block, to the far left i.e. so that `b` and `a` are vertically aligned. I would much rather not have to use a character such as `&` to guide the alignment, I'd prefer to always be the first character of each word after a `\\`.

Comment: i don't think you want the `\\ ` after the last line; that gives you an empty (but numbered) extra line in the output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use `align`. Use `gather` instead.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
b := (a \oplus s_1) \oplus s_2 \\ 
e := 0
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```